Problem while curving objects around a bezier circle


I want to curve these circles around the cylinder at the middle but when I used the curve modifier this happened. anyone knows why this is happening?

Hello, try this: put the origin of your object at its geometry (right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry), and make sure that the object is at the same location as the curve

I think it was because the object wasn't the same location as the curve. thanks!

Do 2 things: Put the origin of your object at its geometry (RMB > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry), and make sure that the object is at the same location as the curve (select the curve and ShiftS > Cursor to Selected, select the object and ShiftS > Selection to Cursor).
